# The information the user inputs does not register into a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, user-interface

I'm working on a project in Python, creating a GUI application. Here is a part of my code:

```
class Register(Frame):
        def __init__(self, master):
            Frame.__init__(self, master)
            self.config(bg = "black")
    
            def register_user():
                username_info = username.get()
                password_info = password.get()
                username_entry.delete(0, END)
                password_entry.delete(0, END)
                file = open(username_info, "w")
                file.write(username_info + "\n")
                file.write(password_info + "\n")
                file.close()
    
    
                Label(register_user, text="Registration Success", fg="black", font=("calibri", 12)).pack()
    
    
    
            Label(self,text="Please enter details below to Register", bg="white").pack()
            Label(self,text="").pack()
    
            username = Label(self, text="Username: ", bg="black", fg="white")
            username.pack()
            entryusername = Entry(self, width=20, bg="white")
            entryusername.pack()
    
            pw = Label(self, text="Password: ", bg="black", fg="white")
            pw.pack()
            entrypw = Entry(self, width=20, bg="white")
            entrypw.pack()
    
            save = Button(self, text="Save", width=8, command=lambda: master.switch(Login))
            save.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
```

My problem is that once the user registers his username and his password, it isn't being saved into a file. So, once the user wants to log in, it says that the user is not found.

I can't figure out what is missing, it would be very nice if someone could give me a hand.

Thanks

Comment: can you add reproduceable code and not only partial code?

Comment: you never run `register_user()` so it can't save it. Maybe in `Button` you should use `command=register_user` and inside `register_user()` add `master.switch(Login)`

Comment: BTW: you use `register_user` as parent for `Label` - it is not correct.

Comment: you get values from wrong widgets. You get `username.get()` but `username` is a `Label`. You should use `entryusername.get()`. And you get `password.get()` but you don't have `password` - you shoul duse `entrypw.get()`. You also try to delete text in `password_entry` but you don't have `password_entry`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never run `register_user()` so it can't save it.

Maybe in `Button` you should use `command=register_user` and at the end of  `register_user()` add `master.switch(Login)`

---

**BTW:**

You get values from wrong widgets. You get `username.get()` but `username` is a `Label`. You should use `entryusername.get()`. And you get `password.get()` but you don't have `password` - you should use `entrypw.get()`. You also try to delete text in `password_entry` but you don't have `password_entry`.

You also use `register_user` as parent for `Label` - it is not correct. Besides after registering it will switch to other `Frame` so it will have no time to display it.

---

Minimal working code with other changes. But I skip code which change to `Login`.

I put `register_user()` as  normal function in class so I need to use `self.` but this makes code more readable.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

class Register(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        
        self.config(bg="black")

        l = tk.Label(self, text="Please enter details below to Register", bg="white")
        l.pack(pady=(0, 10))

        l = tk.Label(self, text="Username: ", bg="black", fg="white")
        l.pack()
        
        self.username_entry = tk.Entry(self, width=20, bg="white")
        self.username_entry.pack()

        l = tk.Label(self, text="Password: ", bg="black", fg="white")
        l.pack()
        
        self.password_entry = tk.Entry(self, width=20, bg="white")
        self.password_entry.pack()

        b = tk.Button(self, text="Save", width=8, command=self.register_user)
        b.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    def register_user(self):
        username_info = self.username_entry.get()
        password_info = self.password_entry.get()
        
        self.username_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        self.password_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    
        file = open(username_info, "w")
        file.write(username_info + "\n")
        file.write(password_info + "\n")
        file.close()

        self.master.switch(Login)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

reg = Register(root)
reg.pack()

root.mainloop()
```